# Passing a PHP value to a twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code. How can I get the value of `['ADMINISTRATOR_ID']` and pass it to the modal box.

I'm kinda new at this view-contact is my modal box. What method should I use get or post?

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($td_admins as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$row[ 'ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$row[ 'FIRSTNAME'];?>
                    <?=$row[ 'LASTNAME'];?>
            </td>
            <td>    <a href="#view_contact" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view" data-id="<?=$row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>" data-toggle="modal">View</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="view_contact" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Admin row number:
                    <?php echo $_POST[ 'id'];?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?? what do you want to do?

Comment: how can I gat the value of data-id="<?=$row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>" and place into my modal body?

Comment: `echo` that value on the page

Comment: copy the value of $row[ 'ADMINISTRATOR_ID'] to a php variable and call that php variable in the modal.

Answer (score 1):

To bind value in bootstrap modal, you have to listen bootstrap event and do what you want in it. You can check these event list on [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($td_admins as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$row[ 'ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$row[ 'FIRSTNAME'];?>
                    <?=$row[ 'LASTNAME'];?>
            </td>
            <td>    <a href="#view_contact" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view" data-id="<?=$row['ADMINISTRATOR_ID'];?>" data-toggle="modal">View</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="view_contact" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Admin row number:
                    <?php echo $_POST[ 'id'];?>
                </p>
                <p>Admin Id:
                    <span id="admin_id"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#view_contact').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { // depend on vary your bootstrap version
        var adminId = $('#admin_id').attr('data-id');
        $('#admin-id').html(adminId);
    });
</script>
```